# undefined is not an object 'this.props.navigation.navigate'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I have this error when I try to call

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView, View, TouchableOpacity, ActivityIndicator , Image} from 'react-native';


export default class Cards extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.card}>
        <View style={styles.card_header}>
          <View style={styles.dir}>

            <Image style={styles.account_img} source={require('../../../assets/png/Group_287.png')} />
            <Text style={styles.header_text}>{this.props.name}</Text>
            <View style={{ justifySelf: 'flex-end', flex: 1, marginRight: 20 }}>
            <TouchableOpacity>
              <Image style={[styles.footer_images, { alignSelf: 'flex-end' }]} source={this.props.image} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
          <Text style={styles.paragraph}>{this.props.text}</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.card_center}>
        <Image style={{width:'100%', height:'100%'}} source={this.props.user_image}/>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.card_footer}>
          <View style={styles.image_container}>
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Image style={styles.footer_images} source={require('../../../assets/png/like.png')} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>

          <Text style={{color: '#EEEFF0'}}>{this.props.likes}</Text>

          <View style={styles.image_container}>
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Image style={styles.footer_images} source={require('../../../assets/png/commenta.png')} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>

          <Text style={{ color: '#EEEFF0' }}>{this.props.comments}</Text>

          <View style={{ justifySelf: 'flex-end', flex: 1, marginRight: 20 }}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Share')}>
            <Image style={[styles.footer_images, { alignSelf: 'flex-end' }]} source={require('../../../assets/png/condividi.png')} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the class i want to navigate

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView, View, TouchableOpacity,Image, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';


export default class Share extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <View style={{height:20, backgroundColor:'red'}}></View>
    )
}


}
```

Routes:

```
  Share: {
      screen: Share,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerLeft: HeaderLeft,
        headerRight: HeaderRight,
        headerStyle: {
          elevation: 0,
          shadowOpacity: 0,
          borderBottomWidth: 0,
        }
      }
    },
```

The class that I want it to be placed is a class that is exported in another component to be able to create component of the same type.
If I use the navigation function in another class that is not exported anywhere, it goes ok. Why does this happen and please help me how to solve?

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the actual error message?

Comment: Clearly, `this.props.navigation` is `undefined` (probably because `navigation` doesn't exist on `this.props`). We can't help you with *why* that is from what's in the question. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: can you show your routes where you have defined navigation.

Comment: @AnkitDubey yes I updated the post

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I updated the code. Please help what is wrong

Comment: please show your entire route file with all navigation you have used. In this case, navigation property does not exist in props that mean you are doing something wrong** while passing navigation to your app**.  post your route file and app.js file so that I can debug your code.